# Display Dynamic Number in WPF TabItem Header

Tags: wpf, binding, tabitem

I have a TabControl where every item contains a User Control called Timeline. This "Timeline" has a property called "Number" which changes during runtime.

I want to make the property "Number" to be displayed in the TabItem header. And i have really no idea how to do that to be honest.

My first thought is that i have to create a Custom Control that derives from the original TabItem Control and create a DependencyProperty or something with a custom ControlTemplate.

I feel that i'm pretty bad on explaining this...

An example: I Want to do something like the third image in the post on following url, but instead of the close-button, i want to display the property "Number" that dynamically changes during runtime!

http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2007/04/08/closeabletabitem.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have this class:

```
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title {get; set;}

    private int number;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
             number= value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }
}
```

We can bind the collection of items to TabControl:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">            
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                    
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                            
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
            </StackPanel>                        
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:TimeLine Number="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```